# Biblatex: labels and sorting

Tags: biblatex

For what reason an entry with an author Volaterrano comes before another entry with an author with name Teixeira? I supposed the shorthand label should give the output:
TP Teixeira
VCom Volaterrano

MWE:

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nt,sorting=debug,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{barreiros1968chorographia,
        author    = {Barreiros, G.},
        title     = {Chorographia de alguns lugares [...]},
        year      = {1561},
        publisher = {por Ioã Aluarez},
        url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=h3-RngEACAAJ},
        address   = {em Coimbra},
        keywords  = {Gaspar Barreiros -- toponímia (latina e portuguesa) -- geografia (história) -- Ânio de Viterbo (recepção) -- sigla},
        shorthand = {BCor},
    }
    
    
    @InBook{vadianuspomponius1530,
        author    = {Vadiano, Joaquim},
        title     = {Pomponii Melae De orbis situ libri tres, accuratissime emendati, una cum Commentariis},
        year      = {1530},
        publisher = {Christ. Wechel},
        ignoreurl = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=OJtoAAAAcAAJ},
        keywords  = {Joachim de Watt -- geografia (séc. XVI) -- sigla},
        shorthand = {VAD},
    }
    
    @Book{Teixeira1583,
        author    = {Teixeira, frei José},
        title     = {De Portugalliae ortu, Regni initiis et denique de rebus à Regibus, vniuersoque Regno praeclare gestis, compendium},
        year      = {1583},
        publisher = {apud Joannem Mettayer},
        address   = {Parisiis},
        keywords  = {sigla},
        shorthand = {TP},
    }
    
    @Book{maffei1559commentariorum,
        author    = {Volaterrano, R.},
        title     = {Commentariorum urbanorum Raphaelis Volaterrani, octo et triginta libri, accuratius quam antehac excusi},
        year      = {1559},
        publisher = {apud Frobenium et Episcopium},
        url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=QeaEVzCCoVcC},
        address   = {Basileae},
        keywords  = {sigla},
        shorthand = {VCom},
    }
    
    
    @Book{pigafetta1906magellan,
        author    = {Robertson, James Alexander},
        title     = {Magellan's Voyage Around the World by Antonio Pigafetta, the Original Text of the Ambrosian Ms., with English translation, notes, bibliography, and index},
        year      = {1906},
        publisher = {The Arthur H. Clark Comp.},
        url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=5OSSPgAACAAJ},
        address   = {Cleveland},
        keywords  = {secundaria},
    }
    
    @Book{hoffmann1987handwoerterbuch,
        title        = {Handwörterbuch des deutschen Aberglaubens. Band 1: Aal - Butzemann},
        year         = {1987},
        editor       = {Bächtold-Stäubli, H. and Hoffmann-Krayer, E.},
        publisher    = {Walter de Gruyter},
        address      = {New York, Berlin},
        ignoreisbn   = {9783110065893},
        ignoreseries = {Handwörterbücher Zur Deutschen Volkskunde Series},
        ignoreurl    = {https://archive.org/details/handworterbuchdesdeutschenaberglaubensband3},
        keywords     = {mitologia (Alemanha) -- folclore (Alemanha) -- secundaria},
    }
    
    @Article{Alarcao2005,
        author   = {Alarcão, Jorge de},
        title    = {Os equívocos dos promontórios Sacro(s) e Cúneo},
        journal  = {Promontoria},
        year     = {2005},
        number   = {3},
        pages    = {251–285},
        keywords = {arqueologia -- geografia greco-latina -- geografia da Península (Antiguidade) --- Avieno -- secundaria},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography[keyword={sigla},title={Abbreviations list}]

\section{Text}
O moço também resolveu não ficar servindo (vide \cite{barreiros1968chorographia}) naquela casa, cuidando que
lhe dariam tempo sem mais nada(vide \cite{maffei1559commentariorum}). Foi-se embora ao outro dia, e chegou
a casa de outro lavrador, que o tomou para o serviço (vide \cite{Teixeira1583}). À ceia disse o moço:
— Ó meu amo, o caldo está muito quente.
— Pois miga-lhe broa (\cite{vadianuspomponius1530}).
O rapaz disse lá para si, que aquela era a casa que lhe convinha (vide \cite{pigafetta1906magellan}), e ali se
deixou ficar\footnote{On the relation between this and that see \cite{pigafetta1906magellan}, and more extensively \cite{hoffmann1987handwoerterbuch}, and more clearly \cite{Alarcao2005}}. 




\printbibliography[keyword={secundaria},title={Bibliografia}]

\end{document}```
````

Comment: you are overwriting the sorting with `sorting=debug`.  This then sorts by entry key.

Comment: Note that instead of `(vide \cite{barreiros1968chorographia})` you can write `\parencite[vide][]{barreiros1968chorographia}`. `sorting=nt,` does not exists, but that does not matter in this example, because you overwrite it with `sort=debug,` which causes unexpected sorting here as explained by Ulrike above. The style combination `style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,` is really odd. ...

Comment: ... The usual way to print a list of sigla/shorthands is `\printbiblist{shorthand}` and not `\printbibliography[keyword={sigla},title={Abbreviations list}]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here?

Comment: @Sintram If people answer your question, you can accept an answer to show that it resolved your question by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left of the answer. You can also vote up (or down) to show if the answer was useful. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. So far you have asked eight questions that received an answer, but accepted none.

Comment: Apologies for not having marked as accepted the valuable answers given so far. Yes the sorting=debug was a problem. I removed it. Thanks for pointing me the existence of the command \printbiblist{shorthand} (p. 94 of the Biblatex manual).